# Is there a function to "merge all layers" in GIMP?

Tags: gimp

It would be more effective. Currently I have to merge them one by one. In some cases it can be a time consuming process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the layers panel, right click a layer and choose *Flatten Image*, or if you want you can choose *Merge Visible Layers* for more options.

Answer (score 2):

Billy Kerr has your direct answer, but it is usually a bad idea to merge your layers. Merging layers is easy, un-merging them when you have regrets is complicated to say the least.

So, other techniques:

- As Billy Kerr says, but duplicate the image first (*Image>Duplicate*), so you keep a copy with distinct layers
- *Select>All*, *Edit>Copy visible*, *Edit>Paste as>New image* (same result)
- *Layer>New from visible* to get a new layer which is the result of the existing layers.
- Put all your layers in a ["layer group"](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-layer-groups.html). For most purpose the group behaves like the flattened image of what is inside (it can have a layer mask, a layer mode, and you can apply transforms on the group)